# this._sui is undefined with semantic-ui-vue and vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, semantic-ui, vuejs3

I m building an app with vue3 and semantic-ui-vue from the bootstrap vue 3.
The app refuse to load, i have the following error in the console :

```
semantic-ui-vue.js?080a:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_sui' of undefined
```

In my app i add the semantic-ui-vue and semantic-ui-css as following :

**main.js file**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import SuiVue from 'semantic-ui-vue';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';

createApp(App)
    .use(SuiVue)
    .mount('#app')
```

And then in my only one component i do the following :

**app.vue file**

```
<template>
    <sui-button>Click Here</sui-button>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
}

#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

If i remove the sui-button, all go fine. The build with webpack is always ok.

Comment: [`semantic-ui-vue` is built for Vue 2](https://github.com/Semantic-UI-Vue/Semantic-UI-Vue/blob/afc18c6/package.json#L125), so it won't work in Vue 3.

Comment: @tony19 thanks for this note, is there an alternative?